# How to add a numeric value with unit (eg. 1500 kW) using WbQuantity() function, unsuccessful using tutorial

Tags: wikidata-api, pywikibot

I'm creating a semi-automated tool in Python, using pywikibot, to import data from TOP500 database into Wikidata, following [this](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Creating_a_bot) and [this](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Pywikibot_-_Python_3_Tutorial/Quantities_and_Units) tutorial. (Is my first time programming in Python).

It ran fine, until the script attempts to commit a numeric value within a unit (for example, [Pleiades (`Q2442043`)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2442043) → [power consumed (P2791)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2791) → 4407.00 **kW**). The script parses the numeric value within the unit, then, the unit is converted to the given statement (**kW** → [kilowatt (`Q3320608`)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3320608)). However, the script throws error (it is a warning due I'm handling errors using try-except) when passing the unit as URL (entity helper string) as well as statement (QXXXXX):

```
WARNING: API error modification-failed: Illegal value: https://wikidata.org/wiki/Q79738
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Davod/Documents/git/wikidata_top500/core/pywikibot/page.py", line 112, in handle
    func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Davod/Documents/git/wikidata_top500/core/pywikibot/page.py", line 4325, in addClaim
    self.repo.addClaim(self, claim, bot=bot, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Davod/Documents/git/wikidata_top500/core/pywikibot/site.py", line 1326, in callee
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Davod/Documents/git/wikidata_top500/core/pywikibot/site.py", line 7946, in addClaim
    data = req.submit()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Davod/Documents/git/wikidata_top500/core/pywikibot/data/api.py", line 2080, in submit
    raise APIError(**result['error'])
pywikibot.data.api.APIError: modification-failed: Illegal value: https://wikidata.org/wiki/Q79738 [messages:[{'name': 'wikibase-validator-not-allowed', 'parameters': ['https://wikidata.org/wiki/Q79738'], 'html': {'*': 'Valor ilegal: <a class="external free" href="https://wikidata.org/wiki/Q79738">https://wikidata.org/wiki/Q79738</a>'}}]; help:See https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes.]
```

I uploaded [my project](https://github.com/Amitie10g/wikidata_top500) to GitHub. Relevant source code is found at the [`addClaim()` function](https://github.com/Amitie10g/wikidata_top500/blob/python/functions.py#L89), [line 109](https://github.com/Amitie10g/wikidata_top500/blob/python/functions.py#L109).